# Preserve quotes in PostgreSQL db call

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a table that has both quoted and non-quoted column names, for example: `username` and `"phoneNumber"`. When I query the database, the columns are both shown without quotes. Currently, I'm using:

```
$array = pg_fetch_all(pg_query($db, $query));
```

Is there any way that I can preserve the quotes when I am querying the rows from the database?

Comment: The double quotes are just there to keep the database from trying to normalize the identifiers to lower case, they're not actually part of the column names themselves. Presumably they're coming back as `username` and `phoneNumber` so, if you know that you're dealing with mixed case names, you could probably get away with double quoting them all the time. Or better, don't use mixed case identifiers at all if you can help it.

Comment: I agree with mu: don't use quoted identifiers at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options.  The traditional advice is "don't use quoted identifiers, just lower case everything."  That's fine and it is preferable because it reduces cases where you run a query against the wrong table or columns by mistake.

The other option is to quote everything all the time.  This way you don't have to worry about preserving quoting because it's always there.

In LedgerSMB we actually do both.  The quoting is done primarily to avoid SQL injection (we run identifiers through functions that return quoted strings).  However we also standardize on lower case names so that quoting doesn't cause problems when one runs queries in psql or the like.  So my recommendation is to use `pg_escape_identifier` consistently and standardize on lower case identifiers.